# Is there a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to ${}^{*}\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

Is there a one-to-one correspondance between the real numbers and the hyperreal numbers?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by ${}^*\mathbb R$. There are structures of different sizes, any of which is a reasonable version of ${}^*\mathbb R$, there is no nice uniqueness theorem here as with the reals. Maybe you mean something more concrete, with ${}^*\mathbb R$ being an ultrapower of $\mathbb R$ by a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$?